# Tasks that throw exceptions block IPython-Parallel queue

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, ipython-parallel

I am using IPython-Parallel's `load_balanced_view` and map to perform some simulations. I use the asynchronous version of the view so it doesn't block.

Whenever the function applied by `map`throws an exception, the `error` property of the asynchronous map is set correctly.
If this happens however the errorous tasks stays in the queue forever. Is there any possibility to cancel/abort it?

As far as I understand it `cancel` and `abort` only work on jobs that are not yet running (waiting in queue).

Any Ideas how to cancel the job so the engine becomes free again?

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in `ipyparallel` and is fixed in master.

The related GitHub issue is [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipyparallel/issues/184).